# Ошибка uninitialized constant DeviseTokenAuth (NameError) (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

После установки гема 'devise_token_auth' сломался проект. После запуска сервера выкидывает ошибку: uninitialized constant DeviseTokenAuth (NameError)

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему удалением гема '$ gem uninstall devise_token_auth', а также всех файлов под именем DeviseAuth...,и удалением миграции "devise_token_auth". После написал в консоли '$ rails db:rollback'.